# Simple JQuery Image Fade in Fade Out Having Trouble

Tags: jquery, html

I am have an image I want to fade in and out and then show a Div. And then when clicked fade back to the previous image and hide the Div. It works perfectly to show the div but the reverse is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    <div id="calcDrop"><img id="plusCalc" height="33px" align="left" class="plusCalc changePad" alt="plusButton" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/calculator/plusBig300.jpg" />
    <img height="34px" align="left" class="changePad" alt="Calculate Price" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/calculator/calcDrop300.jpg" />
    </div>

    <script>


    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


        jQuery('.plusCalc').click(function(){


                    jQuery('.plusCalc').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},function(){
                    jQuery('.plusCalc').attr('src', '/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/calculator/minusBig300.jpg');
                    jQuery('.plusCalc').attr('class', 'minusCalc');
            }).load(function(){
                    jQuery('.minusCalc').stop().animate({opacity:'1'});
            });

            jQuery("#calculatorDiv").show('slow');


        });


          jQuery('.minusCalc').click(function(){

                jQuery('.minusCalc').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},function(){
                    jQuery('.minusCalc').attr('src', '/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/calculator/plusBig300.jpg');
                    jQuery('.minusCalc').attr('class', 'plusCalc');
            }).load(function(){
                    jQuery('.plusCalc').stop().animate({opacity:'1'});
            });

            jQuery("#calculatorDiv").hide('slow');

        });



    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use two images positioned on top of each other, then use jQuery's **fadeToggle** to rotate between the two.

Something like this (http://jsbin.com/ibofis/12/edit) might do the trick. You could also change it to just fade in and out the one on top, removing the second instance of **fadeToggle** on each.